# Magento - My "Add to Cart" button will not work and product list formatting is off.

Tags: html, css, magento

Yesterday I posted a question on here about changing the size of my product list in Magento.  [Ara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1640660/ara) was very helpful when it came to addressing my issues and I have made a lot of progress.  But, I've now encountered a couple new issues I'm hoping someone can help me with.

Currently, the listing of products on my site looks like this: http://soundcherry.com/index.php/sound-effects.html

This was achieved by modifying part of the list.phtml file (app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml) and also the styles.css files (skin/frontend/default/f002/css/styles.css).

After making my modifications though, the add to cart button in the product listing no longer works.  So, considering my lack of knowledge, it seems likely I've messed something up.  The code for the button in the list.phtml file currently looks like this:

```
<p style="display:inline"><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class= button btn-cart""onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button><P>
```

What did I mess up?

Also, the amount of spacing around each product in list view is a bit much.  Is there anyway I can reduce the amount of space?  The piece of my styles.css file that deals with list view looks like this right now:

```
/* View Type: List */
.products-list li.item { border-bottom:1px solid #d9ddd3; padding:1px 1px; }
.products-list li.item.last { border-bottom:1px; padding:25px 1px; }
.products-list .product-image { float:left; width:40px; height:40px; margin:0 0 1px; }
.products-list .product-image img { width:40px; height:40px; }
.products-list .product-shop { margin-left:55px; }
.products-list .product-name { margin:0 0 5px; font-weight:bold; font-size:13px; color:#203548; }
.products-list .product-name a { color:#203548; }
.products-list .price-box { float:left; margin:3px 13px 5px 0; }
.products-list .availability { float:left; margin:3px 0 0; }
.products-list .desc { clear:both; padding:6px 0 0; margin:0 0 15px; line-height:1.35; }
.products-list .desc .link-learn { font-size:11px; }
.products-list .add-to-links { clear:both; }
.products-list .add-to-links li { display:inline; }
.products-list .add-to-links .separator { display:inline; margin:0 2px; }
```

I don't see anywhere to fix the spacing.  Am I missing something, or is it going to be in another file?

I'm a complete amateur with html/css as well as Magento, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using firebug i can see the bellow mentioned html code of add to cart button where i can see an error.

```
 <button btn-cart""onclick="setLocation('http://soundcherry.com/index.php/sound-effects/this-is-a-test-product.html?options=cart')" class="button" title="Add to Cart" type="button"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
```

The correct syntax will be

```
<button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://soundcherry.com/index.php/sound-effects/this-is-a-test-product.html?options=cart')"  title="Add to Cart" type="button"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped me get the button working again.  Now there's another odd issue.  It seems that because these products are downloadable products, when add to cart is clicked, it simply brings the customer to the product page and says "please specify the products required options."  There's nothing to specify, so it requires that you then click add to cart again on the products page to actually put it into the cart.

Is there anyway to change this?  So that clicking add to card on the product list page just immediately adds it to the cart?

Comment: For this you need to modify on this page /app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Product/Type.php . Check http://www.evermoretechnologies.com/blog/2011/03/31/magento-1-5-downloadable-products-error-when-adding-to-cart/ AND http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/220106/#t301915

Comment: If above solution helped you then plz marked it as a correct solution.Will appreciate if U vote me as well :).

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I'd rate you up but I don't have the reputation to do so.

Comment: Also, for some reason, the code changes discussed at both of the links you provided me do not seem to work for me.  I either get an error, or it continues to do the same thing as before.  I'll keep searching and trying things.

Comment: @Mac. hello mac you know what I m also new in magento but trying to solve your issue since last 1 hour,finally I found a solution. No need to change any core file of magento .You just set 'Links Can be Purchased Separately' option as 'No' in downloadable information tab. I have tested in version 1.7.0.2 and it works for me. If it not works for existing product you add a new downloadable product check new one.Hope it will work for u.:)

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right.  I tried the "links can be purchased separately" option as both yes and no many different times, but it never would work.  With a new product though, it now works.  It must need to be set as no from the very beginning or it won't work.  Anyway, thank you so much for your help!  Now if I can just get the spacing on my product list view to be uniform, I'll be set.  : /